# Changing frontname in config.xml does not change url

Tags: magento-1.8

I am trying to change the URL structure for a third-party extension. I have changed the frontName attribute in config to "sellers" and cleared cache but, when I access [www.mysite.com/sellers](http://www.mysite.com/sellers) I still receive a 404 page. The old name of the URL "mpsellerlist" still works though. Is there somewhere else I should be looking to change it? Here is my config.xml where I have made changes:

```
<frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mpsellerlist module="Webkul_Mpsellerlist">
                    <file>mpsellerlist.xml</file>
                </mpsellerlist>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <mpsellerlist>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Webkul_Mpsellerlist</module>
                    <frontName>sellers</frontName>
                </args>
            </mpsellerlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

**Note:** I am not sure if this is affecting it, but we do have static pages set up one level below "sellers" - ex: [www.mysite.com/sellers/how-to-sell.html](http://www.mysite.com/sellers/how-to-sell.html). Would that cause /sellers to be unavailable for a frontName attribute?

Comment: yes I cleared cache and the static pages below sellers/ still work.

Comment: did you test naming it `sellers2` works? if you are on Apache server, it could be that your `.htaccess` overrides will keep you in the directory `sellers` and not redirecting to the `index.php` of Magento.